# ng2 - DevExtreme vs Telerik Kendo UI

Tags: angular, devextreme, kendo-ui-angular2

We are starting a new software  using Angular2, typescript and HTML5.

We have 2 options for UI components: 
- DevExtreme
- Telerik Kendo UI

Which one is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

We faced the same question, or almost the same: KendoUI, DevExtreme or IgniteUI for a new application where the UI is build in Angular2.
Our PoC led to the choice of DevExtreme. The main reason was the extensive documentation and demo's which led to fast development.

Comment: We've been users of Kendo UI for all the same reasons (good documentation, good demos). It's just that their jQuery version is mature, their Angular2 version is not yet. Apparently DevExtreme is in the lead on this at the current time. That may be partly because the Progress developers are also building out their NativeScript mobile app development stuff at the same time. And BTW, I don't work for Progress/Telerik, just a fairly happy user of their products.

Comment: I have been an avid user of telerik/progress for years but the slow development of the angular 2 framework is forcing me to switch.  For example, they don't have documented integration with ionic, they don't have a scheduler component and basic component such as a multselect tag editor are not done cooking.

Answer (score 5):

I should say you need to specify your software requirements first. Then, you need to try out both of them and choose which one better meets your particular needs. Here are advantages I can see:

Telerik Kendo UI for Angular 2:

1. Supports server-side rendering
2. Has a smaller library size
3. Might work faster in particular cases (no jQuery inside)

DevExpress DevExtreme for Angular 2:

1. Much more components and features
2. Faster delivery of new features (no extra resources needed for ng2 support)
3. More that [250 demo use cases](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/WindRose/Angular/Light/) with working code samples

P.S. DevExtreme for ng2 has [removing jQuery](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/46) in their roadmap. So, it will become faster and support server-side rendering as well.

Answer (score 2):

Kendo UI for Angular 2 is designed specifically for Angular 2, with each feature carefully aligned to the framework guidelines (there are no jQuery dependencies): [Announcing: Kendo UI for Angular 2 (2016 R3)](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/announcing-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-(2016-r3))

DevExtreme seems to be based on jQuery, but I could be wrong.